# AWS CodeCommit Markdown Table of Contents

Tags: markdown, aws-codecommit, tableofcontents

How do you make a Table of Contents (ToC) in a Markdown file in AWS CodeCommit?

Working in VS Code, I've tried to create a ToC in this form:

```
# Table of Contents
1. [Section](#section-one)
2. [Section2](#section-two)
3. [Section3](#section-three)


## section-one
## section-two
## section-three
```

And also in this form:

```
# Table of Contents
1. [Section](#section-one)
2. [Section2](#section-two)
3. [Section3](#section-three)

## This is first <a name="section-one">
## This is second <a name="section-two">
## This is third <a name="section-three">
```

I have also tried replacing "name" with "id" in the anchor tags in the latter example.

I have no problem getting a nice looking ToC but I cannot use it to navigate the document. When I click a section in the ToC, the main page of the repository is loaded, showing the files in the repository followed by the Readme.

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case, I see the <a> as normal text in CodeCommit. I have the feeling that CodeCommit does not have this feature, which sucks.

Comment: @Nikola.grancharov I think you're right. I still haven't found a solution.